# Swf file to be packaged in an apk (Android)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash, flash-cs5

I have an android tablet. I made a swf file with mouse events, it rotates images to right and left. I wanted to put it on Android and run it as an .apk file which consists of the swf file embeded within it.
I tried running the swf file through webView it works perfectly fine. But i wanted to make it as an application. Can you please let me how to do this

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run `.swf` files packaged as `.apk` files using `Adobe Flash CS5`. Using the application, you just need to create a `swf` file with the stage size equivalent to the resolution of the screen and then while publishing, just publish it as an `.apk` file. You can either run it directly on your phone connected to your PC by using the `USB Debugging mode` in Android or simply download the .apk file and install it like any other application on your device. In CS5, you need the `Air for Android` plugin to package your `swf` file as an `apk` but in CS5.5, this feature is present by default. Hope this helps.

Here's the link for the CS5 extension : http://kiran.dhoux.com/air-for-android-extension-for-flash-cs5-to-develop-apps-for-android-devices/